# Create a discussion board/ forum embedded in SharePoint

Tags: discussion-board, community-site, sharing

I would like to pick your brain on the following issue:

I am looking to create a discussion board, basically something similar to SharePoint Stack Exchange site: A site where users can share and answer to each other questions.

How I would like it to be is also similar as how this site works.

- A user ask a question which can be answered by everyone.
- Once answers appear, I would like to rate the answers so that the most rated rise to the top and show first.
- Questions are tagged to ease their search.
- Users earn reputation based on their contribution and the quality of their answers.

I am just wondering if it is possible to have such a site embedded in a SharePoint site.

What about the Discussion board tool available in SharePoint, would that be an option to consider? If not, what would be your recommendations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint 2013 or later, create a subsite based on the "Community Site" template. It supports questions and answers, and even a point based scoring system with titles/metals if you like. Tagging will not work exactly the same, but you can create categories of questions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mike.
I am afraid we are using SharePoint 2010... community sites are not available for the 2010 version?

Also, within the community site, is it possible to create alerts when questions are answered?

Comment: Community Sites were added with SP 2013. Yes, you can create alerts.